# Is there a built in way to get C# coverage output on the CLI?

Tags: c#, testing, code-coverage

I've been looking through the coverage docs for C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2022#code-coverage-formats

and it looks like the only formats it outputs are xml files?

I'd really like to see coverage both on my command line and CI (from `dotnet test`) in a format more like ruby's Simplecov Console:

```
COVERAGE:  82.34% -- 2345/2848 lines in 111 files

showing bottom (worst) 15 of 69 files
+----------+--------------------------------------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------+
| coverage | file                                       | lines | missed | missing                                     |
+----------+--------------------------------------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------+
|  22.73%  | lib/bixby/api/websocket_server.rb          | 22    | 17     | 11, 14, 17-18, 20-22, 24, 28-30, 32, 36-... |
|  30.77%  | app/models/role.rb                         | 13    | 9      | 28-34, 36-37                                |
|  32.14%  | lib/bixby/modules/metrics/rescan.rb        | 28    | 19     | 19-23, 27-31, 33-37, 39-41, 43              |
|  42.86%  | lib/archie/mail.rb                         | 14    | 8      | 6-8, 12-15, 22                              |
|  44.00%  | lib/archie/controller.rb                   | 50    | 28     | 18-21, 23, 27-30, 32, 38-40, 44-45, 48-4... |
|  44.44%  | app/models/metric_info.rb                  | 9     | 5      | 38-40, 42, 44                               |
|  46.15%  | lib/bixby/modules/notifier.rb              | 13    | 7      | 13-14, 27-28, 38-40                         |
|  46.15%  | lib/archie/otp/controller.rb               | 26    | 14     | 15-18, 21, 26-27, 31, 33-34, 36-38, 41      |
|  46.88%  | app/controllers/rest/models/hosts_contr... | 32    | 17     | 7, 19-22, 24, 28-30, 32, 36-38, 42-44, 48   |
|  47.83%  | lib/bixby/hooks.rb                         | 46    | 24     | 54, 68-70, 72-74, 84-86, 88-90, 104, 111... |
|  48.28%  | app/controllers/rest/models/checks_cont... | 29    | 15     | 5, 7-8, 10, 13, 34, 38-40, 44-45, 47, 49... |
|  48.44%  | app/controllers/application_controller.rb  | 64    | 33     | 19, 35-37, 57, 59-64, 67, 88, 92, 107, 1... |
|  50.00%  | app/views/models/repo.rb                   | 12    | 6      | 10, 12-13, 16-17, 20                        |
|  54.55%  | lib/ext/sidekiq_logging.rb                 | 11    | 5      | 9, 15-17, 19                                |
|  60.00%  | app/views/models/check_template.rb         | 10    | 4      | 10-13                                       |
+----------+--------------------------------------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------+
42 file(s) with 100% coverage not shown
```

Comment: You've tried to write an XSLT script to convert the XML to your desired output?

Comment: I don't know XSLT (or XML parsing in C#) which is why I'm asking if a non-xml solution exists. Preferably something plaintext I can see in my CI